# How do I resize the seek bar / progress bar in jplayer?

Tags: javascript

Can't find it in jquery.jplayer.min.js ? Maybe it isn't defined yet, but I can't find anything but size of the complete player. I can copy the full file if that helps anyone.

Comment: No, don't copy the whole file, post a [mcve] as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50449697/edit) to your post.

Comment: Not the whole file but still complete? I'm pretty sure it's defined in one way only, so hopefully anyone knows.

Comment: No. Complete does not mean posting the while file. What you should do is post the relevant code needed to reproduce the problem you are having.